# c# recursion on method calls once itself after return

Tags: c#, recursion, return, call

```
    private static string FindBookEanOrEanOnSplits(string[] splits, int index = 0)
    {
        string id = "";
        if (index < 3)
        {
            id = Extractor.ExtractBookEanOrEan(splits[index].ToUpper());

            if (id == string.Empty)
                FindBookEanOrEanOnSplits(splits, index + 1);
        }

        return id;
    }
```

for example, after on **second call**, the **id** is **no longer empty** then jumps out to return **but calls for once(suddenly goes back) on this line FindBookEanOrEanOnSplits(splits, index + 1) that makes the id empty** instead having not empty value

Comment: What is your question? I did not understand it!

Comment: You miss id = FindBookEanOrEanOnSplits( ... )

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this recursively anyway?  You could just do it in a loop:

```
private static string FindBookEanOrEanOnSplits(string[] splits)
{
    string id = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        id = Extractor.ExtractBookEanOrEan(splits[index].ToUpper());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) break;
    }

    return id;
}
```

Recursive calls can be confusing to debug.  It's entirely unnecessary in this case because you're only doing a simple index operation and calling another method.  Recursion is useful when you're dealing with data structures or operations that are naturally hierarchical in nature and require the maintenance of "state" at each level.

Comment: for loop is even faster than recursion... :)